# Consumir API Rest desde Node JS y recoger resultados en Angular 4

Tags: nodejs, api, angular4

Buenos días. Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Angular 4 que realiza llamadas diversas a una API Rest, y dicha API hace referencia a una base de datos que esta en un servidor. Las llamadas a dicha API las estoy realizando con Angular 4 del siguiente modo:

Este es la peticion que se hace al hacer submit en un formulario (en este caso el de Login):

```
onSubmit(isValid:boolean){  
  this._resultado.getLogin(this.inicio_Sesion).subscribe(
    result=>{
      if(result.count == 1){
        localStorage.setItem( 'idUsuario', result.his[0].id);
        this._logeado.setValue(true);
        this._estado.navigate(['/panelUsuario']);
      }else{
        this._estado.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    },
    error=>{
      var errorMessage = <any>error;
      console.log(errorMessage);
    }
  );
}
```

Y este es el fragmento que realiza la peticion GET a la API:

```
getLogin(data:any){
    this.consulta= this.url+"?param%5Bdni%5D=" + data.dni+ "&param%5Bpwd%5D=" + 
         data.pwd + "&api_key=API_KEY";

    return this._http.get(this.url, {params: data})
        .map(res => res.json());


}
```

La variable URL contiene la IP del servidor donde se encuentra la API Rest.
El problema de esto esta en que, si habrimos la consola de desarrollo en cualquier navegador podemos ver todos los datos de la API Rest. 
Supongo que la unica forma de evitar esto seria realizando dicha consulta en un lenguaje orientado a servidor como PHP o Node JS (estoy mas interesado sobre todo en este ultimo porque creo que me ofrecera mayor flexibilidad a la hora de trabajar con Angular).
La pregunta es, ¿como puedo realizar consultas a la API desde Node para que los resultados sean tomados por Angular 4?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con que se vean las llamadas en la consola? Es lo habitual y no es peligroso, al fin y al cabo el API es pública

Comment: Te explico, en la API se muestra IP del servidor, api key, ect... Es cierto que una API es publica, pero un parametro como es una API KEY se ve por el navegador perfectamente, ademas de todos los datos que se escriben por el navegador. Por ejemplo,en PHP se puede hacer una peticion CURL y enviarle parametros, de este modo, esa consulta quedara invisible a simple vista. Por lo tanto, Node JS, que es tambien un lenguaje orientado a servidores debera ser similar en este aspecto.

Comment: Por otro lado, si yo realizo una consulta a una API y la web se encuentra en HTTPS, me dara un error de que recibe una respuesta insegura, por lo que el navegador bloqueara la peticion y no se completara.

Comment: Si usas API REST va a ser públicas estas llamadas, la solución sería que el servidor te devolviera incluso el código que tiene que leer el navegador, pero creo que no es lo que quieres. Te recomiendo que busques guías de seguridad web con API REST, controles todo lo que recibe en la parte del servidor y securices la url para que nadie pueda entrar dónde no debe.

Comment: Y a lo de https, existen maneras de controlarse también el cross scripting, que es por lo que puede fallarte con el https ;)

Comment: @AntonioMP87 La API Key identifica a un usuario, y es el usuario el que puede ver esa API Key mientras navega... sigue sin ser un riesgo de seguridad

Comment: Entiendo que desde angular estás haciendo llamadas a una API rest con un API KEY que no es tuyo, es decir, no lo has proporcionado tú (no es para hacer uso de to endpoint), correcto eso está fatal de narices. Tienes que hacer un endpoint en tu backend que haga esa consulta para evitar que ese API KEY de otro servicio en el que tú estás registrado sea visible por los clientes de tú aplicación.

Comment: Asumiendo que el escenario es el que @F.bernal expone, la pregunta es demasiado amplia: necesitas montar un servidor propio donde tu aplicación se conecte para pedir datos. Dicho servidor obtendría los datos usando el API REST y se los devolvería a tu aplicación web. Pero todo eso es demasiado para una respuesta en SO, requiere muchos pasos

Comment: Probaste implementar JWT usando OAuth, despues por definicion las API REST son publicas